# jQuery validation plugin question

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I have a web form that is using this awesome plugin and I'm trying to set up a rule.  In my form, I have a Quantity field.  If the Quantity field is set to 1 AND a checkbox is checked, then I want to validate a field.

My form is setup like:

```
Quantity      TEXTBOX      id = txtQuantity
Gift?         CHECKBOX     id = #other
Recipient     TEXTBOX      id = txtRecipient
```

and my jQuery code is:

```
txtQuantity: "required",
txtRecipientEmail: { required: "#other:checked" },
```

I tried:

```
txtRecipientEmail: { required: "#other:checked", required: "$('txtQuantity').val() == '1'" }
```

but that's not working

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`required` can take a function as well](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback), which is what you want here:

```
txtRecipientEmail: { 
  required: function() { 
    return $("#other:checked").length && $("#txtQuantity").val() == '1'; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Since I'm going to try this in a little while, if the checkbox is checked, I assume that length will return 1 else 0, right?

Comment: @coson - yup, absolutely right, if it makes it clearer feel free to stick a `> 0` in there, even though JavaScript works either way :)